# Binding lifetime of a newly created variable

Tags: rust

I'm getting familiar with Rust lifetime guarantees and I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible.

The code panics on the line before the last when `unwrap`ing. The compiler correctly understands that `persons_with_age` must live at least until `persons_and_zip_code_city_map.persons` lives; but I'd like to signal to the compiler that I want it to live until the whole `persons_and_zip_code_city_map` lives because there's an implicit reference to `persons_and_zip_code_city_map.zip_code_city_map`. Perhaps I could do this with some zero-sized types, or using lifetimes in some way?

This would make this runtime error become a compile-time error.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[allow(dead_code)]
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct Person {
    name: String,
    zip_code: u32,
    useless_data: u16,
}

#[allow(dead_code)]
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct PersonWithAge<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
    age: u16,
    zip_code: &'a u32,
}


type ZipcodeCity = HashMap<u32, String>;

struct PersonsAndZipcodes {
    pub persons: Vec<Person>,
    pub zip_code_city_map: ZipcodeCity,
}
    
fn get_persons_with_zip_map(code: u32) -> PersonsAndZipcodes {
    let persons = vec![
        Person { name: "a".to_string(), zip_code: code, useless_data: 10 },
        Person { name: "b".to_string(), zip_code: code, useless_data: 20 },
    ];
    
    let mut zip_code_city_map = HashMap::new();
    zip_code_city_map.insert(code, "street1".to_string());

    return PersonsAndZipcodes {
        persons,
        zip_code_city_map,
    }
}

fn get_persons_ages() -> Vec<u16> {
    vec![30, 40]
}

fn main() {
    // Here I get a vector of Persons (contains a zipcode) and a HashMap from a zipcode to a city.
    // I make sure that every zipcode listed has an entry.
    // While I could have added the city to the Person {}, this would use more memory,
    // since N people can have the same zip_code, which would be added only once to the hashmap.
    let mut persons_and_zip_code_city_map = get_persons_with_zip_map(1);
    let persons = persons_and_zip_code_city_map.persons;
    
    // Another API returns the ages of the persons
    let ages = get_persons_ages();

    assert!(persons.len() == ages.len());
    
    // Here persons_with_age is created attaching the Age to a new object.
    let mut persons_with_age = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..ages.len() {
        persons_with_age.push(
            PersonWithAge {
                name: &persons[i].name,
                age: ages[i],
                zip_code: &persons[i].zip_code,
            }
        );
    }

    println!("{:?}", persons_with_age);

    // Here I get a reference to an specified person
    let this_person = persons_with_age.get(0).unwrap();

    // persons_and_zip_code_city_map is updated
    persons_and_zip_code_city_map = get_persons_with_zip_map(2);

    // Now I try to access the zipcode of `this_person` I have.
    // My logic guarantees that `persons_and_zip_code_city_map.zip_code_city_map` would
    // have this zipcode at the time I acquired `this_person`, but now it has been updated
    // and the zipcode doesn't exist anymore.
    // If I had assigned `persons.get(0).unwrap()` to `this_person`, the compiler catch this
    // mistake, but it doesn't because I'm using `persons_with_age`.
    // Is it possible to perhaps bind the lifetime of `persons_with_age` with `persons_and_zip_code_city_map`?
    let this_person_city: String = persons_and_zip_code_city_map.zip_code_city_map.get(&this_person.zip_code).cloned().unwrap();

    println!("{:?} {:?}", this_person, this_person_city);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cc0d408af4b48e51d472a31b9e02d2dc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are moving out the `persons` array, to a local variable and then you borrow that other variable:

```rust
let persons = persons_and_zip_code_city_map.persons;
```

That is what allows overwriting `persons_and_zip_code_city_map` later, it is partially moved, but not borrowed.

The solution is to borrow the value instead:

```rust
let persons = &persons_and_zip_code_city_map.persons;
```

Then when you borrow from `persons` you are actually borrowing from `persons_and_zip_code_city_map`, so that will not modifiable.

You can forbid moving the `persons` member by making it private, and writing an accessor function:

```
impl PersonsAndZipcodes {
    pub fn persons(&self) -> &[Person] {
        &self.persons
    }
}
```

You can even nest this type into an inner module so that your main module cannot access its private parts.

Another method to forbid moving out member variables would be to implement `Drop`:

```rust
impl Drop for PersonsAndZipcodes {
    fn drop(&mut self) {}
}
```

But implementing `Drop` just to avoid moving out its members looks a bit hackish to me.